# Calling InsertAsync from static function throws ThreadAbortException

Tags: c#, azure

I expect there's probably a simple fix for this but I just can't see it.

I'm trying to insert data into an Azure Mobile Services DB from a C# Console program.  However when the program is run from within VS (via F5), the data is not being inserted nor is an exception being thrown (that I can see) during the regular course of running the program.  When I set a breakpoint to the `await dataModel.InsertAsync(data)` line and run that in the Immediate Window it throws a ThreadAbortException.  Any help is appreciated.

```
Namespace TestApp {
class Program
{
    public static MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
    "https://x.azure-mobile.net/",
    "API key");

    public static IMobileServiceTable<performance> dataModel = Program.MobileService.GetTable<performance>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var test = new performance("http://www.example.com");
            var x = InsertItem(test);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
static public async Task InsertItem(performance data)
{
        await dataModel.InsertAsync(data).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
}

class performance
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "uri")]
    string Uri { get; set; }

    public performance(string uri)
    {
        Uri = uri;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What happens when you put a breakpoint on the var x = InsertItem(test) line and inspect x? I suspect you'll find that it's a task and there is no corresponding run call...but...I'm just guessing.

Comment: Markus - actually, when I set the breakpoint and F11 through, the debug session just stops directly after the `InsertAsync` call.

Comment: Wow...so, if you put Console.WriteLine(x.Status); after the var x = InsertItem(test) line, it never hits the console line?

Comment: I put together a simple test to try and replicate what you're seeing. At first, the task returned by my InsertItem method was returning a status of RanToCompletion. After I modified the async method called by InsertItem (InsertAsync) to put a task on the thread pool that took more significant time to complete, I get similar behavior to what you describe when stepping through the code. When stepping over the code, the task status is returned as WaitingForActivation. After I put Task.WaitAll(x) between var x = InsertItem(test) and the console write, it worked and task status was RanToCompletion.

Comment: (I am probably over-simplifying this.)

Comment: And that works!  Which I find somewhat strange due to the fact I was waiting for things to complete when I had the breakpoint triggered.  Want to write up an answer so I can approve?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a small test to (somewhat) simulate what you're doing. When the awaited task in InsertItem takes very little or no time at all, the task returned by the var x = InsertItem(test) line returns a task in the RanToCompletion state and the debugger acts as expected.

However, when I make the awaited task do something substantial, such as Thread.Sleep(5000), then I get the behavior you're describing and the task returned by the var x = InsertItem(test) line returns a task in the WaitingForActivation state.

When I put Task.WaitAll(x) following the var x = InsertItem(test) line, then I get the behavior that I think we both expect and x.Status is RanToCompletion.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem comes from the fact that `var x = InsertItem(test);` is a non blocking call. When you get to `await dataModel.InsertAsync(data).ConfigureAwait(false);` the function `InsertItem` immediately returns with a `Task`.

Normally the correct approach would be do `await InsertItem(test);` however because your code is being called from `Main` you can't make the function `async`. So for this **console application** (it would not be the correct choice if running in WinForms or WPF app) You need to put a `x.Wait()` before the end of your `try-catch` block.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var test = new performance("http://www.example.com");
        var x = InsertItem(test);

        //This makes the program wait for the returned Task to complete before continuing.
        x.Wait();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

However if you where to do this in a WPF or WinForms app you would just make the calling function (Assuming the function was a event) async.

```
private async void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var test = new performance("http://www.example.com");

        //The code now waits here for the function to finish.
        await InsertItem(test);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

**Do not do `async void` function calls unless you are in a event delegate function**